# VBA delete sheets based on criteria

Tags: excel, vba, conditional-statements, delete-file, worksheet

I would like to create a Macro on VBA that should completely delete a sheet if a specific value is less than another one in another sheet.

So i got sheet1, for example, where in range "A1" there is a date.
Now i would like that all the other sheets (in reality just some of them, but i can accept also for all the others if there is no solution) compare a value, for example in Cell "B10", that contain a formula that as output have a date. 
If from the compare the value is behind the date in sheet1 THEN you have to delete the sheet.

Thank you.

Comment: Please attempt to answer the question yourself and ask when you get stuck, providing the code you have written. This is not a code writing service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need something like this... Just step through all the worksheets in the workbook (backwards, because you're deleting sheets) and test against `Sheet(1)`, or wherever your main sheet is... You didn't give enough details, but you need to specify which sheet your testing against or this just won't work.

```
Sub Test()

Application.DisplayAlerts = False

For i = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Count To 2 Step -1
    If Sheets(i).Range("B10").Value < Sheets(1).Range("A1").Value Then
        Sheets(i).Delete
    End If
Next i

Application.DisplayAlerts = True

End Sub
```

Comment: It actually works but he constantly delete all the sheets. In sheet 1 there is the data where all the others must compare their ones with. @dwirony EDIT: i have tried to put such 01/01/2025 (sheet2) compared to 01/01/2020 (sheet1) and excel delete it

Comment: @Rufyyyyy What is your data being formatted as? This was done assuming your data is written in `Date` format.

Comment: It is in data format but i always receive the message from excel -> "Do you want to delete this sheet?" and by clicking yes it delete it

Comment: Yes sir, this is what i mean. I have checked by right click, select format, as date

Comment: @Rufyyyyy We can turn off that notification, I edited my code. But my sample data is written in `Date` format, I've tested it and it works just fine. Are you sure your test date is in cell `A1` on your main sheet and in  `B10` on the other sheets???

Comment: This is crazy actually, i am sure. Just explain me how you set as Date cause maybe  i am doing some crazy error

Comment: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/format-a-date-the-way-you-want-8e10019e-d5d8-47a1-ba95-db95123d273e This is how i made that cell being a Date

Comment: @Rufyyyyy  I don't think the date formatting is the issue, I think it's what `Sheets(1)` is in your workbook. If you open the VBA editor, in the leftside panel under "VBAProject (Book1)" your sheets are listed. Find your main sheet's name there, and what is the Sheet # next to it?

Comment: Cause my excel is in Italian, i read Foglio 1 (that is the traduction of sheets 1) and son on -> Foglio 2, Foglio 3, etc...

Comment: And Foglio 1 is where your date in cell A1 is?

Comment: Yes, Cell A1 in Foglio 1

Comment: @Rufyyyyy What was the issue?

Comment: something about the formatting, i don't know why i have seen that it actually stacked and did not go as date, sorry about that i am still a newbie

Comment: @Rufyyyyy No worries -